# Do we have authorship rankings in our field or related fields?

Tags: reference-request, history, education

I was reading about the field of "[energy economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_economics)" and found it fascinating that there is a list of "top 20" authors:

[image]

At first this seemed strange: What does it even *mean* to be the #4 best energy economist?

**However they seem to have a [rigorous procedure](https://ideas.repec.org/top/) for evaluating people's research based on several criteria, and they update the results between the 3rd and 5th days of each month.**

They also have "top author" lists specifically for women, young people, deceased, and by where they graduated:

[image]


I'm fascinated by the level of detail with which I can search and sort:


[image]

**Do we have something like this for people that model matter?** 
**How about for any field of computational/theoretical (bio)chemistry/physics?**

[Four of the top researchers in our field have been mentioned on Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/121697/93303) in a "fun" answer, but it was based on *ad hoc* criteria involving h-index, age, and perhaps personal opinion: Surely we can do better.

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: @Camps Now's your chance to be #1 in Brazil, and #1 that graduated from University of Havana!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the answer is currently seems to be "no" but this could change in the future

Comment: I've just learned that the notion of "ranking scientists" [also exists in the biomedical scince field](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046418300248?via%3Dihub).